# syntax error (missing operator) two user in login form

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax-error, operator-keyword

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Username ='admin' [Password] ='admin' AND AccountType = Admin''.
```

Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jen\Documents\Jade\vb\database.accdb")

```
    txtAdmin.Text = "Admin"

    Dim strsql As New OleDbCommand("select * from Login where Username ='" & txtUsername.Text & "' [Password] ='" & txtPassword.Text & "' AND AccountType = Admin'", conn)
    Dim uu As New OleDbParameter("UserName", txtUsername.Text)
    Dim pp As New OleDbParameter("Password", txtPassword.Text)
    strsql.Connection.Open()

    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    reader = strsql.ExecuteReader

    If reader.HasRows Then
        strsql.Connection.Close()


        MsgBox(" Successfully Logged in!", vbInformation)

        frmIndex.Show()
        desktopFade.Close()

    ElseIf txtUsername.Text = "" And txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Don't leave the fields blank", vbCritical)
        txtUsername.Focus()

    Else

        MsgBox("Your Username or Password is invalid", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Me.txtUsername.Text = ""
        Me.txtPassword.Text = ""
        Me.txtUsername.Focus()
        strsql.Connection.Close()


    End If
```

i have 2 user in the database. the admin and the user. if the username and password account type is = Admin then ADMIN Account show while if the username and password input is for the user then USER Account show. On my code, i'm trying to solve first the admin but i need everyone help. T.T

Answer (score 0):

You miss an "AND" here:

```
'" & txtUsername.Text & "' [Password] ='"
```

Should  be

```
'" & txtUsername.Text & " AND ' [Password] ='"
```

Comment: geez . thank you really !! i spent 2 hrs searching for an answer . seriously . thanks ^^

Comment: @JadeMendoza if that answers the question tag it as answered